# Is there a way in r to use a character list of object names to mutate these objects with base::lapply and dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, lapply, dplyr

I'm quite new to that topic and might not be able to express myself in the right terms. What I want to do is to do the same operation to several objects in my workspace.

Therefore I generate a list of these objects and try to feed this list to lapply which feeds it subsequently into mutate. One of the new columns should contain the type (e.g. "Experiment" or "exp") and the other the name of the respective object (e.g. "iris2"). The required result is achieved with mutate(iris2, type = "exp", name = "iris2") but I get errors when I try to feed a list into the construct. I searched for two days but I cannot find a working solution. Example code is below.

Thanks for any help with this,
Stephan

```
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris
iris4 <- iris

mutate(iris2, type = "exp", name = "iris2")

file_list <- list("iris2", "iris4")

my_fun <- function(x) { 
  as.name(x) %>%       
    mutate(type = "exp", name = as.character(x))
}

result <- file_list %>% lapply( my_fun )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are passing a character string representing the name of the data frame you wish to work with. When you call `as.name(x)` inside your function, you are literally passing a symbol as an argument to `mutate` rather than the data frame to which that symbol refers. If you want to access the object to which a symbol refers, you need to `eval` that symbol, so you could use `eval(as.name(x))`.

However, the shortcut in R for getting an object from its symbol name is `get(x)`, which is equivalent to `eval(as.name(x))` :

```r
my_fun <- function(x) mutate(get(x), type = "exp", name = as.character(x))

result <- lapply(file_list, my_fun)
```

This gives the intended result as we can see if we look at the `head` of the two data frames in `result`:

```r
lapply(result, head)
#> [[1]]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species type  name
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris2
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris2
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  exp iris2
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  exp iris2
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris2
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  exp iris2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species type  name
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris4
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris4
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  exp iris4
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  exp iris4
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  exp iris4
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  exp iris4
```

Note that this kind of thing isn't necessary if you keep multiple similar objects together in a list. It feels a bit alien at first to have your data frames inside a list, but when you have to carry out operations across multiple data frames, it makes it much easier. For example, you could have just done:

```r
iris_list <- list(iris2 = iris, iris4 = iris)
```

and you can access each data frame easily with `iris_list[[1]]` and `iris_list[[2]]` etc, which doesn't add many keystrokes. You can also get rid of the need for `file_list` and a separate function, since you can achieve everything in a single line with:

```r
Map(function(x, y) mutate(x, type = "exp", name = y), iris_list, names(iris_list))
```

If at any point, you want the data frames back in your global environment you can do `list2env(iris_list, globalenv())`

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I wanted. Is there a way to do this and overwrite the original data frames. Meaning that I keep separate mutated data frames?

Comment: @Stephan yes, you can, but I wouldn't recommend it. You should get used to working with multiple data frames inside lists, particularly if you are going to carry out the same operation on them. See my update showing how it is easier to work with your data frames in a list, and how to put them in the global environment if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks again Allan. This costed me already two days trying on my own with little success and now this looks so easy ;) You made my day!

Comment: I have an additional question if I want to manipulate elements of data frames in lists. For example, I have several data frames in the list containing the same columns but some of the observation columns are not present in all data frames. Can I compare those data frames inside the list and store them as a new list of data frames containing only the columns present in all data frames?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(file_list, ~ get(.x) %>% 
          mutate(type = "exp", name = .x) )
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, this does what it should do but I do not fully understand the ~get(.x) term. Could you maybe explain what the function does. I used the help on it but I do not fully understand it.

Comment: @Stephan the `file_list` is a list of object names as strings that is created in the global env, `get` returns the value of that object from the global env and then we `mutate` on that object with a new column.  The output from `map` is a `list` and it will not update the original object though.  If you need to update it, you may need `list2env` on a named `list` output

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.